# Is the 6 bit opcode binary value the same as 6 bit funct binary value for mips?

Tags: assembly, encoding, binary, mips

I'm having a little misunderstanding with encoding regarding finding the func and opcode binary bits. To my understanding func is the same as opcode and you find the opcode by just references the Mips green sheet.

I have created my own example here, and tested in mars which didn't match my work

my work

```
add $t0, $t0, $t0
```

`add` opcode  = `000000`

`$t0` = the either register, so the 5 bit binary value is `01000`

`shamt` = because theres no shift amount here `00000`

`funct` = `000000`

all together i would get `000000 01000 010000 010000 00000 000000` 

which should be `0x01084000`
but I am getting `0x01084020` under the mars code column of the execute tab. which would make sense if my `func` = `100000`. So I am assuming my there is something wrong with my understanding for encoding the `func` and `opcode` section.

Comment: 000000 just does not mean ADD.  It is used for many instructions, the funct part selects the specific one.  ADD is 01000, SLL is 00000.  Page A50 in [this pdf](http://www.math.unipd.it/~sperduti/ARCHITETTURE-1/mips32.pdf) has a good map.

Comment: Think of `funct` as a sub-opcode for `opcode` 0